# How to hide Wordpress upgrade message in Admin Panel?

Tags: wordpress

How do we hide upgrade now message in admin panel for wordpress 2.9.2 ? is there's any ? i use

> add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
>   add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

but it seem it's not working.

Comment: no this is a programming related. It's about hooking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
add_action('admin_menu','bhhidenag');
function bhhidenag()
{
   remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
```

You can read more about it in the blog-entry where I found this:
http://www.websitesecrets101.com/how-to-hide-wordpresss-update-now-notification

Answer (score 1):

Run an upgrade. The message will go away.